# JavaScript scoping and function call

Tags: javascript

I'm have C++ and Java background. I'm having some trouble understanding function calling in JavaScript.

Below is my code example, I declared variable lon and lat #4. and assign it value on line #5 and #6.

Here is my question, I made a call to writeToTes() on #1 and it worked. But when I placed writeToTes() on #2 or #3, lon and lat is empty, like it was never assigned. Why is that?

according to my logic, we already executed if(navigator.geolocation){}, lat and lon should already be assigned, why is it when I made call to writeToTes() lon and lat is still empty.

```js
var lon = '',
  lat = ''; // #4 

$(document).ready(function() {
  setLonLat();
});

function setLonLat() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      lat = (position.coords.latitude); //#5
      lon = (position.coords.longitude); //#6
      writeToTes(); //#place it Here  #1
    });
    //#place it Here  #2
  }
  //#place it Here  #3
}

function writeToTes() {
  $("#tes").html(lon + " " + lat);
}
```

Comment: That's because of asynchronicity, that's why you pass the callback function - it get's called when the result is received. If you place the variable outside of the callback handler, you'll see it's state before something was assigned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `getCurrentPosition()` is an asynchronous operation. The function you pass to `getCurrentPosition()` is called a callback function. Any code put into this function is executed after the current position is retrieved.

When you place `writeToTest()` after the call to `getCurrentPosition()`, it is executed BEFORE `getCurrentPosition()` has finished executing. Therefore, `lat` and `lon` have not been assigned to yet.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the variable that was assigned in the callback function and still be able to access outside of the callback function?

Comment: You will still be able to access it outside of the callback function, but this isn't a good thing to do because you don't know when it has been assigned. Hence, you want to execute all code depending on the location within the callback. If you want to make this code more neat, use Promises.

Comment: @Hadaz Zeilberger Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It is like adding an `eventhandler` on a button click. The `eventhandler` will only fire once the button is clicked. In this case, your `eventhandler`, or `callback`, is invoked when you get a geolocation. You callback has the position which contains your `lat` and `lon` data.